# A Key Error is returned when I try and use df.index.get_loc(recession_start)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to find the when the recession has ended by observing trends in consecutive values in the column of a df. I want to return the quarter when the GDP has risen consecutively for two quarters.

I've already pinpointed when the recession started in the following function:

```
def get_recession_start():
    df = get_data()
    for i in range(1, len(df) - 1):
        if (df.iloc[i]['GDP'] < df.iloc[i - 1]['GDP']) and (df.iloc[i + 1]['GDP'] < df.iloc[i]['GDP']):
            return df['Yearly quarters'].iloc[i]


get_recession_start()
```

I want to use this function to find the precise index  of the above function (get_recession_start()) to search the df from that point.

```
def get_recession_end():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = get_data()
    recession_start = get_recession_start()
    index = df.index.get_loc(recession_start)
    for i in range(index + 2, len(df)):
        if (df.iloc[i]['GDP'] > df.iloc[i-1]['GDP']) and (df.iloc[i - 
1]['GDP'] > df.iloc[i - 2]['GDP']):
            return df['Yearly quarters'].iloc[i]

get_recession_end()
```

```
I would expect this function to return the single string value '2008q3', however, instead I'm getting a traceback message:


KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: '2008q3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-5f3688935fbb> in <module>
     11             return df['Yearly quarters'].iloc[i]
     12 
---> 13 get_recession_end()

<ipython-input-16-5f3688935fbb> in get_recession_end()
      6     df = get_data()
      7     recession_start = get_recession_start()
----> 8     index = df.index.get_loc(recession_start)
      9     for i in range(index + 2, len(df)):
     10         if (df.iloc[i]['GDP'] > df.iloc[i-1]['GDP']) and (df.iloc[i - 1]['GDP'] > df.iloc[i - 2]['GDP']):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: '2008q3'
```

Comment: please post more data, not because we all want to know when the recession will end given the current economical solution ;-), but because with more data (especially input dataframe & expected output), we can suggest better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that *get_recession_start* returns a value from *Yearly quarters* column
(from the row for the quarter the recession started).

You call this function in `recession_start = get_recession_start()`, so *recession_start*
contains the quarter the recession started (something like *yyyy*q*n*).

Then your code contains `index = df.index.get_loc(recession_start)`, so you call
*get_loc*, passing the quarter "name" just found.

And just this is the source of error, since *get_loc* looks in the index
(probably a sequence of numbers) for just this passed value (probably *2008q3*).

Apparently, this index does not contain the passed value, so the exception
raised is just *KeyError: '2008q3'*.

To correct your program:

- find the **key value** for this row,
- pass it to *get_loc*.